# Get user list with whom OneDrive Document is shared using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using Graph API to read OneDrive document successfully.
I have a requirement to get the list of users with whom the document is shared with. 
The DriveItem does have the **Shared** property but it only tells whether is shared with user\organsization\anonymous, however it does give me list of users with whom I have shared the document.

As per [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/shared)

> The Shared resource indicates a DriveItem has been shared with others.

```
{
  "owner": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet" },
  "scope": "anonymous | organization | users",
  "sharedBy": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet" },
  "sharedDateTime": "datetime"
}
```

Is there a way to get shared with "users list" for a given document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API supports this via the [Permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/permission) resource. Permissions define the level of access provided (`read,`write`,`sp.owner`, or`sp.member`).

You can return a [list of Permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_permissions) using the `//permissions` endpoint of a given file. For example, to `/me/drive/items/{item-id}/permissions` will return the permissions for the `{item-id}` in the current user's default `Drive`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yes that does give  the permission. The permission  resourse returns just the displayname, Do I have to make another resource call to get the email Id as well?

Comment: It should provide both `displayName` and `id`. To get the email address you can make an additional call to `/users/{id}` to get the profile.

Comment: It sometimes doesn't provide an id. I'm not sure why. I created a new question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722348/missing-id-property-in-identity-resource-type-microsoft-graph-api